# socket can't communicate with netcat bash

Tags: python, sockets, netcat

On a vm I used the command: nc -l -p 8221 -e /bin/bash and made a python3 script:

```
def netcat():
    print ("starting connection")    
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("192.168.1.60", 8221))
    while True:
        user = input("what to send?: ")
        s.sendall(bytes(user, "utf-8"))
        time.sleep(5)
        word = "bob"
        data = s.recv(4096)
        if data == b"":
            pass
        else:
            data = data.decode("utf-8")
            print ("Received:", repr(data))
    print ("Connection closed.")
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    s.close()
netcat()
```

this script doesn't work. By don't work I mean when I  run a command with my python script, lets say "pwd", it just loads but never runs.
When, instead of running the python script I would run nc 192.168.1.60 8221, it would work fine. Any ideas why?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Do you get an exception from `connect`? What's the error message?

Comment: @JohnKugelman   I'll edit the question, good comment

Comment: What do you mean it "loads but never runs"? Do you see `starting connection`? If you hit Ctrl-C, what line was it stuck on? Please be as detailed as you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `input()`'s [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string
>   (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

But Bash is operating in canonical mode and won't process input till a new line arrives. This won't happen, leading to `recv` blocking forever.

add a `+ '\n'` after the `user = input("what to send?: ")` to fix it.

Comment: It is indeed the answer to my question but there is still something strange. Lets say there was a mistype (ex: pwds) there is simply nothing output, no "bash syntax error".

Comment: Errors are written to `stderr`, not `stdout`. use `-e '/bin/bash 2>&1'` to have netcat send both streams to the client.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I have 1 last question, lets say I would like to let the user make a new request without receiving any response, do I have to use the threading module? I would like to emplement other services (ex: ftp) independantly. EX: I still communicate to nc while ftp is connecting or a nmap scan running at the same time.

Comment: With `select` you can wait on the socket and stdin at the same time. Then you can run processes in background e.g. `(sleep 2s; echo 'hello') &` and receive their output asynchronously. But remember, for serious use, there is `ssh`.

Comment: I do not understand the background processes. To clarify, the processes are not started on the remote host, it is my host that starts them. I thought that the only way possible was with threading, os or subprocess. Were you talking about any of these in your example?

Comment: Ah, I thought you are talking about having long-running commands on the remote host. My first sentence still applies. you can wait simultaneously on multiple sockets with `select`/`poll`. No need to fork/thread for every new connection.

Comment: I can't get to make it run. Since we talked I am trying to make it work. The documentation about select ain't really descriptive on how to use it. I posted a new question with the updated script if you have time to watch it! Might get some points there. Thanks again for the answer. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856264/python3-read-and-write-socket-asynchronously-with-select-module